# Calling lifecycle.addObserver from a Kotlin abstract class

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class, android-lifecycle, addobserver

I have an abstract class that implements `DefaultLifecycleObserver`. I'd like to call `lifecycle.addObserver(this)` from the `init` block, but it says **"Leaking 'this' in constructor of non-final class MyAbstractClass"**.

My code:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass(protected val activity: AppCompatActivity) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    init {
        activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I can move this line of code to the init block of each final class that extends this abstract class, but I don't like the idea, especially because I want to guarantee that each new class that will extend MyAbstractClass in the future will call it as well.
Is there a better place to call this without creating a leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could post your call so it only happens after the object is fully instantiated:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass(protected val activity: AppCompatActivity) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    init {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Or it might be less surprising to create an extension function you can tack onto your constructor calls. Then you can explicitly start the observation immediately. You'd have to make `activity` public, though. By defining it in an extension like this, your subclasses can call this and return themselves so you can chain it to constructor calls.

```
fun <T: MyAbstractClass> T.alsoBegin(): T {
    activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    return this
}

val foo = SomeImplementation(myActivity).alsoBegin()
```